# How to create backorder from python in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I am odoo newbie. My goal is to create a method in python that will create backorder from unfinished delivery order and will allow me to skip the user input in wizard.

Basically it should have the same functionality as when user clicks on Validate button and then chooses Create Backorder in wizard, but without the user input in wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to use the method inside of **stock.picking**

Try this:

```
backorders = your_picking_id._create_backorder()
```

It'll generate and return backorder for remaining quantity from your current delivery order.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit `stock.picking` and override the `_pre_action_done_hook` method to create the backorders instead of returning the confirmation wizard.

```
class StockPicking(models.Model):
_inherit = 'stock.picking'

def _pre_action_done_hook(self):
    vals = super(StockPicking, self)._pre_action_done_hook()
    if isinstance(vals, dict):
        if (
            vals.get('type') == 'ir.actions.act_window' and
            vals.get('res_model') == 'stock.backorder.confirmation'
        ):
            pickings_to_validate = self.env.context.get(
                'button_validate_picking_ids')
            if pickings_to_validate:
                pickings_to_validate = self.env['stock.picking'].browse(
                    pickings_to_validate).with_context(skip_backorder=True)
                return pickings_to_validate.button_validate()
    return vals
```

The code block inside above `if` statement, is taken from `process` method of `stock.backorder.confirmation` which is the method linked to the `Create Backorder` button on the wizard. You can read the method in `stock/wizard/stock_backorder_confirmation.py`.